# Portable way to tell the compiler that alignment is OK without supressing the warning?

Tags: c, gcc, casting, clang, compiler-warnings

One of the tests we run is a compile with `-Wcast-align`. Its especially helpful when an incorrect cast occurs among floats, doubles and integrals (it will sometimes lead to a ***`SIGBUS`***, IIRC).

We have code that essentially performs the following. The actual cases are a little more involved, but this is the essence of the usage:

```
typedef uint64_t word64;

static const size_t SIZE = ...;
word64 buffer[SIZE] = ...;
```

And:

```
DoSomethingWithBuffer(const byte* buff, size_t size)
{
    word64* ptr = (word64*)buff;
    ...
}
```

The buffer is aligned on an 8 or 16 byte boundary. I've verified the alignment using both manual code reviews and runtime asserts.

The problem is both GCC and Clang warn that the data is unaligned. And it does so nearly 2000 times, so I'm potentially losing real findings. For example:

```
warning: cast from 'const byte *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') to 'word64 *'
(aka 'unsigned long long *') increases required alignment from 1 to 8 [-Wcast-align]
    word64 tmp = *(word64 *)inBlock ^ roundKeys[0];
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

With Clang, I can instrument with an ***`assert`*** and the compiler will sometimes take it as a diagnostic hint. But it does not appear to apply in this case. That is, Clang does not make the connection that ***`assert(inBlock % 8 == 0);`*** means its aligned.

How can I convey to the compiler that the buffer is aligned without suppressing the warning?

Comment: 1) use `stdint.h` fixed-width types. 2) what is wrong with `alignas` from C standard? 3) your code might invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Olaf - Thanks. Our testing program is fairly comprehensive. We require the code to pass though security gates from Clang and GCC Undefined Behavior Sanitizer, which explicitly test for unaligned access. We also require it to pass Valgrind, Coverity and Microsoft Enterprise Analysis. In addition, the assert explicitly checks for the condition and does not fire. So I don't believe it suffers UB in this particular area (and I hope in no areas).

Comment: Sth. like that might do: word64* ptr = (word64*) ((intptr_t) buff); But probably too hackish? ;)

Comment: You might try putting it in a union with another type that the compiler aligns, e.g. `double`.

Comment: You did not even check what the `alignas` (resp. `_Alignas`) specifier is for I assume.

Comment: @Olaf - Correct me if I am wrong, but ***`alignas`*** is a C++11 feature, isn't it? Also see [C and C++ Alignment Compatibility](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3190.htm) from open-std.org.

Comment: @Ctx - We support back to Fedora 1 with GCC 3.x and Windows 2000 with Visual C++ 6.0. There's no such thing as *too hackish* when trying to appease decades worth of compilers from different vendors :)

Comment: @jww: It is also a C standard feature since C11. Remember there is only one C standard. FYI, the feature was added to both languages intentionally (similar to atomics, btw.)

Comment: @jww I see, you are in a very special hell ;)) Well, maybe just go with that then, should be quite portable

Comment: If worst comes to worst, you could temporarily suppress the diagnostic: `#pragma GCC diagnostic push`, `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcast-align"`, …your dubious line of code…, `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop`.  But that's 4 lines where you previously had one — worst has to be close to worst.

Comment: Why does function have signature `DoSomethingWithBuffer(const byte* buff, size_t size)` instead of `DoSomethingWithBuffer(const word64* buff, size_t size)`?

Comment: @Chux - to save on code size. Sometimes the buffer is 128-bit aligned and it processed by the MMX co-processor; other times its 64-bit aligned and processed by the main cpu; and other times, it is byte aligned. So rather that triplicating code, we provide one function. We also have the appropriate defines in place to guard for the conditions, and the self tests to perform functional evaluations.

Comment: So why is not the signature `DoSomethingWithBuffer(const void* buff, size_t size)` just like `memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);`?

Comment: @Chux - I suspect its a design decision because in crypto, its bytes in, bytes out. Its been that way for about 20 years. Would a ***`void*`*** tame this problem?

Comment: Perhaps something as simple as `void DoSomethingWithBuffer(const byte* buff, size_t size) { const void* buffv = (const void*) buff; const word64* ptr = buffv; ...` which maintains same function signature.

Comment: @chux Good idea, even shorter: `word64* ptr = (void*) buff;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As OP existing code base does not need strong type matching, simple defeat most type matching with `void*` which will quiet the warnings.  Ref also [@Ctx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967728/portable-way-to-tell-the-compiler-that-alignment-is-ok-without-supressing-the-wa?noredirect=1#comment57672196_34967728)

```
 void DoSomethingWithBuffer(const byte* buff, size_t size) {
   const word64* ptr = (void*) buff;
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks again. That worked out really well. it took me two days to clear about 2500+ ***`-Wcast-align`*** warnings (mostly in swaths, like changing 1 macro fixed 50 findings at a time). Of the 2500+ or so, two were legitimate findings.

Answer (score 3):

This makes Clang happy, but will add redundant computation (so, it's probably not OK for release builds):

```
uint64_t y = *(uint64_t *)((uintptr_t)x & ~7UL);
```

With GCC you can use `__builtin_assume_aligned`. Quote from [GCC Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html):

> Built-in Function:
>
> ```
> void * __builtin_assume_aligned (const void *exp, size_t align, ...)
> ```
>
> This function returns its first argument, and allows the compiler to
>   assume that the returned pointer is at least align bytes aligned. This
>   built-in can have either two or three arguments, if it has three, the
>   third argument should have integer type, and if it is nonzero means
>   misalignment offset. For example:
>
> ```
> void *x = __builtin_assume_aligned (arg, 16);
> ```
>
> means that the compiler can assume `x`, set to `arg`, is at least 16-byte aligned, while:
>
> ```
> void *x = __builtin_assume_aligned (arg, 32, 8);
> ```
>
> means that the compiler can assume for `x`, set to `arg`, that `(char *) x - 8` is
>   32-byte aligned.

There is also a [patch](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16294) for LLVM to implement __builtin_assume_aligned, but it has not been merged yet. Similar intrinsic function [exists](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/data-alignment-to-assist-vectorization) for Intel Compiler. Not sure about Visual Studio.